# Converting syntax diagram to ebnf

Tags: ebnf

I am a bit confused atm.

[image]

Should the ebnf form for this syntax graph be:

Prog::= a|b

Or

Prog::= a[b]

Comment: Your first BNF means either `a` or `b`; the second one means `a` optionally followed by `b`.  Which one do you think the diagram represents?

Comment: @luqui Ohh umm I think its the second one. Which makes sense because a is the declaration unit of the program and b is the implementation unit. So must have the declaration and optionally the implementation of the program.

Comment: @koazgamer, to check your understanding, try drawing the diagram for the other one.

Comment: Another technique is to trace your finger along the diagram and see which symbols you can pass on your way from the beginning to the end.

Comment: @luqui Yep my bad the diagram represents the first one. For the second ebnf, the diagram would have the optional b **after** the a.